# Is it possible to compute $x^{1389}+(1/x)^{1389}$ from some premises?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Suppose that we have $ x+(1/x)=1$, can we compute the expression $x^{1389}+(1/x)^{1389}$ from that? and how?

Comment: Hint: $x^3 = -1$. Pretty sure it's a duplicate question, though.

Answer (score 1):

From the first equation, $x = (-1)^{1/3}$. Now, plug this into the second equation and see what you can say about $(-1)^{1/3\cdot1389} + \frac{1}{(-1)^{1/3\cdot1389}}$.

**Hint:** What is $-1$ raised to an odd power?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $x+ 1/x=1 \iff x^2-x+1=0 \implies x^3+1=(x+1)(x^2-x+1)=0$.

Therefore $x^3=-1$ so $x^{1389}=(x^3)^{463}=\cdots$